# Including a variable value in a XSL select path is not working

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I can't quite get my head around this.

So I have this external XML data file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Translations xmlns="http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/msa">
  <en>
    <Chairman>Chairman</Chairman>
    <Conductor>Conductor</Conductor>
    <Hospitality>Hospitality</Hospitality>
    <Prayer>Prayer</Prayer>
    <PublicTalk>Public Talk</PublicTalk>
    <Reader>Reader</Reader>
    <ServiceTalk>Service Talk</ServiceTalk>
    <Speaker>Speaker</Speaker>
    <Theme>Theme</Theme>
    <WTStudy>Watchtower Study</WTStudy>
  </en>
</Translations>
```

It is referenced in my master XSL script like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="Translations" select="document('Workbook-S-140-Compact_2020_v2_Translations.XML')"/>
```

I am able to extract values from this XML file like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Translations/msa:Translations/msa:en/msa:ServiceTalk"/>
```

The above will pull out the English translation. Here is the thing, in my main XML data file I have the following at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Workbook-S-140-Compact_2020_v2.xsl"?>
<MeetingWorkBook>
    <Settings>
        <LanguageCode>en</LanguageCode>
        <Direction>ltr</Direction>
        <EditorMode>1</EditorMode>
        <ForeignGroupMode>0</ForeignGroupMode>
        <Now Day="20" Month="2" Year="2020"/>
    </Settings>
```

Notice the `LanguageCode` entry? I wanted to make use of this so that my transformation was based on the language code. So I initially added a second variable to my XSL file:

```
  <xsl:variable name="LangCode">
    msa:<xsl:value-of select="//Settings//LanguageCode"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

And adjusting my path like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Translations/msa:Translations/{$LangCode}/msa:ServiceTalk"/>
```

But it doesn't like it. I can't work out how to insert the language code into the path query. I have lots of these translation lines so I am looking for a simple solution if possible.

---

I have also tried saving the variable as:

```
  <xsl:variable name="LangCode">
    <xsl:value-of select="//Settings//LanguageCode"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

And then using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Translations/msa:Translations/msa:{$LangCode}/msa:ServiceTalk"/>
```

It still fails.

Is it possible to adjust this line:

```
<xsl:variable name="Translations" select="document('Workbook-S-140-Compact_2020_v2_Translations.XML')"/>
```

So that `$Translations` is pointing to the `Translations/langcode` node? Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use attribute value templates to dynamically construct an XPath expression.

But you can use variables in predicates:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Translations/msa:Translations/msa:*[local-name() = $LangCode]/msa:ServiceTalk"/>
```

Comment: Excellent! Works a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Great! :) (For next time, please make a self-contained sample, e.g. on XSLT fiddle. It's really hard to figure out why certain things don't work when the code in the question consists of unrelated three-liners that leave out many important bits.)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Tomalak's correct answer, you made several mistakes:

Firstly:

```
  <xsl:variable name="LangCode">
    msa:<xsl:value-of select="//Settings//LanguageCode"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

There are several things wrong here. First, the whitespace that precedes "msa:" is part of the value of the variable, and will cause matching to fail. Secondly, using paths with multiple "//" operators is quite unnecessarily expensive. Thirdly, you're constructing a result tree fragment when it would be much simpler to construct a string:

```
<xsl:variable name="LangCode" select="concat('msa:', //Settings/LanguageCode)"/>
```

Next, you're misunderstanding the way variables work in XPath. Variables represent values, not parts of expression text (it's not a macro language like a shell script, it's an expression language like Javascript). Your variable can be used wherever you might use a string literal in quotes, for example `[contains(., 'fred')]` can become `contains(., $var)`. It can't be used in place of parts of the expression where a string literal wouldn't be allowed. And curly braces for textual substitution work only in a few well-defined contexts, they are never used to replace parts of an expression (at least, not until you get to shadow variables in XSLT 3.0, but that's an advanced topic...)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I will have a go with these refinements.

Comment: Your sample did not compile. So I tried `<xsl:variable name="LangCode" select="concat('msa:', //Settings/LanguageCode)"/>` which does compile. But then I tried `<xsl:value-of select="$Translations/msa:Translations/*[local-name() = $LangCode]/msa:ScheduleHeading"/>` and nothign is showing up.

Comment: In the first instance I just had to add that close brace `)` to the `concat` call. But I don't understand why the subsequent attempts to extract values from `$Translations` were failing.

Comment: I must be doing something  wrong. But the accepted answer method is working great.